# Guardar cambios (update,delete) de una tabla en otra tabla en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Estoy buscando una forma para que al momento de que mis usuarios realicen un cambio en una tabla, los cambios del update (datos nuevos) y datos originales (datos viejos) se almacenen en otra tabla por ejemplo tengo la tabla Empleados y tengo este registro con la estructura de su tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
create table RHEMPLEADO(
CLAVE varchar(20),
NOMBRE varchar(200),
DPTO varchar(20),
PUESTO varchar(20),
SEXO varchar(20),
RFC varchar(20),
DIRECCION varchar(200),
COLONIA varchar(200),
MUNICIPIO varchar(200),
EDO varchar(200),
PAIS varchar(200),
FECHA_INGRESO datetime
FECHA_BAJA datetime
constraint PK_secciones primary key(CLAVE)
);
```

Lo que me interesa saber principalmente es los cambios en DPTO, PUESTO, FECHA_INGRESO y FECHA_BAJA; ya que me gustaría tenerlo en una tabla externa solamente con el histórico de cambios que ha tenido un Empleado.

Me explico con un ejemplo:

- Juan Juárez entró por primera vez a la empresa el día 13/02/2020 en
  el Dpto 5 (Producción) en el Puesto 10 (Empacador) y se salió el día
  23/06/2020
- Reingresó el día 10/07/2020 en el Dpto 5 (Producción) en el Puesto 11
  (Cargador) y se salió el día 17/10/2020
- Reingresó por última ves el día 10/12/2020 en el Dpto 4
  (Mantenimiento) en el Puesto 3 (Auxiliar) y sigue laborando.

Y quisiera ver si se pueden guardar los campos:
CLAVE, DPTO, PUESTO, FECHA_INGRESO, FECHA_BAJA
En una nueva tabla llamada EmpleadosCambios (por ejemplo) que es donde estaría el histórico de las actualizaciones de los usuarios.
Esto cada que la FECHA_INGRESO cambie se genere un registro nuevo, ya que en base a este campo es con el que me interesaría que se registraran los cambios en dicha tabla.

No se si me di a entender.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas sobre los triggers en sql. Cuando hayas intentado algo, si tienes un error concreto, seguro que alguien te ayudará. Aparte, te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos en SO. Un saludo y bienvenido.

Answer (score 0):

Ok me explico mejor.
Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
create table RHEMPLEADO(
CLAVE varchar(20),
NOMBRE varchar(200),
DPTO varchar(20),
PUESTO varchar(20),
SEXO varchar(20),
RFC varchar(20),
DIRECCION varchar(200),
COLONIA varchar(200),
MUNICIPIO varchar(200),
EDO varchar(200),
PAIS varchar(200),
FECHA_INGRESO datetime
FECHA_BAJA datetime
constraint PK_secciones primary key(CLAVE)
);
```

En la cual tengo el siguiente registro

```
INSERT INTO RHEMPLEADO 
VALUES(1199,JUAREZ NEPOMUCENO JAIR,2,106,'M','ASDFESEF13444', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2020-12-21 00:00:00.000', NULL)
```

Y creé otra tabla, para los registros de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TABLE RHEMPLEADOLOG(
CLAVE varchar(20),
DPTO varchar(20),
PUESTO varchar(20),
FECHA_BAJA datetime,
FECHA_REINGRESO datetime,
constraint PK_secciones primary key(CLAVE)
);
```

Ahora bien, lo que me interesa obtener es la FECHA_REINGRESO cuando la FECHA_INGRESO cambia. Creé el trigger de la siguiente forma:

```
go
create trigger RHEMPLEADO_UPDATE on RHEMPLEADO
after update
as
insert into RHEMPLEADOLOG (CLAVE, DPTO, PUESTO,FECHA_BAJA,FECHA_REINGRESO) 
select CLAVE, DPTO,PUESTO,FECHA_BAJA,GETDATE()
from deleted
go
```

Pero al momento de hacer un Update creo que me da mal los registros :/ ya que aunque el campo de FECHA_INGRESO no haya sido cambiada.